# fl_chart scatter chart touch tooltip disappears when holding

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

I used the sample code from the github and only changed 1 variable: the handleBuiltInTouches to true, I expect it to have the tooltip pop up when I hold it, but it popped up for a splitsecond before disappearing.

also when I set handleBuiltInTouches to true, even when showingtooltipIndicators has selected all spots, none of the spots have the tooltip popup.

```
class ScatterChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScatterChartSample2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ScatterChartSample2State();
}

class _ScatterChartSample2State extends State {
  int touchedIndex = -1;

  Color greyColor = Colors.grey;

  List<int> selectedSpots = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Card(
        color: const Color(0xff222222),
        child: fl.ScatterChart(
          fl.ScatterChartData(
            scatterSpots: [
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                4,
                4,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(0) ? Colors.green : greyColor,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                2,
                5,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(1) ? Colors.yellow : greyColor,
                radius: 12,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                4,
                5,
                color:
                    selectedSpots.contains(2) ? Colors.purpleAccent : greyColor,
                radius: 8,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                8,
                6,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(3) ? Colors.orange : greyColor,
                radius: 20,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                5,
                7,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(4) ? Colors.brown : greyColor,
                radius: 14,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                7,
                2,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(5)
                    ? Colors.lightGreenAccent
                    : greyColor,
                radius: 18,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                3,
                2,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(6) ? Colors.red : greyColor,
                radius: 36,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                2,
                8,
                color:
                    selectedSpots.contains(7) ? Colors.tealAccent : greyColor,
                radius: 22,
              ),
            ],
            minX: 0,
            maxX: 10,
            minY: 0,
            maxY: 10,
            borderData: fl.FlBorderData(
              show: false,
            ),
            gridData: fl.FlGridData(
              show: true,
              drawHorizontalLine: true,
              checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => true,
              getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) =>
                  fl.FlLine(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
              drawVerticalLine: true,
              checkToShowVerticalLine: (value) => true,
              getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) =>
                  fl.FlLine(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
            ),
            titlesData: fl.FlTitlesData(
              show: false,
            ),
            showingTooltipIndicators: selectedSpots,
            scatterTouchData: fl.ScatterTouchData(
              enabled: true,
              handleBuiltInTouches: true,
              touchTooltipData: fl.ScatterTouchTooltipData(
                tooltipBgColor: Colors.black,
                getTooltipItems: (fl.ScatterSpot touchedBarSpot) {
                  return fl.ScatterTooltipItem(
                    'X: ',
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      height: 1.2,
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    bottomMargin: 10,
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '${touchedBarSpot.x.toInt()} \n',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'Y: ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          height: 1.2,
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: touchedBarSpot.y.toInt().toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
              touchCallback: (fl.FlTouchEvent event,
                  fl.ScatterTouchResponse? touchResponse) {
                if (touchResponse == null ||
                    touchResponse.touchedSpot == null) {
                  return;
                }
                if (event is fl.FlTapUpEvent) {
                  final sectionIndex = touchResponse.touchedSpot!.spotIndex;
                  setState(() {
                    if (selectedSpots.contains(sectionIndex)) {
                      selectedSpots.remove(sectionIndex);
                    } else {
                      selectedSpots.add(sectionIndex);
                    }
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fl` will give the return `fl.FlTapDownEvent` and `fl.FlLongPressEnd` if you give long press.

Set `fl` condition like this:

```
// Show tooltip if tap down detected
if (event is fl.FlTapDownEvent) {
     final sectionIndex = touchResponse.touchedSpot!.spotIndex;
     setState(() {
        selectedSpots.add(sectionIndex);
     });
// Hide/clear tooltip if long press was ended or tap up detected
}else if(event is fl.FlLongPressEnd || event is fl.FlTapUpEvent){
     setState(() {
        selectedSpots.clear();
     });
}
```

**Don't forget to choose and set one between 1-3 condition**

I found that you can show the tooltip if inside `scatterTouchData`:

1. `enable:false` and `handleBuiltInTouches: false`
2. `enable:false` and `handleBuiltInTouches: true`
3. `enable:true` and `handleBuiltInTouches: false`

but not for `enable:true` and `handleBuiltInTouches: true`
Who knows why this happened? I'll updated if I found the answer or you can comment to complete the answer.

Full code

```
class ScatterChartSample2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScatterChartSample2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ScatterChartSample2State();
}

class _ScatterChartSample2State extends State {
  int touchedIndex = -1;

  Color greyColor = Colors.grey;

  List<int> selectedSpots = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Card(
        color: const Color(0xff222222),
        child: fl.ScatterChart(
          fl.ScatterChartData(
            scatterSpots: [
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                4,
                4,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(0) ? Colors.green : greyColor,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                2,
                5,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(1) ? Colors.yellow : greyColor,
                radius: 12,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                4,
                5,
                color:
                selectedSpots.contains(2) ? Colors.purpleAccent : greyColor,
                radius: 8,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                8,
                6,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(3) ? Colors.orange : greyColor,
                radius: 20,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                5,
                7,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(4) ? Colors.brown : greyColor,
                radius: 14,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                7,
                2,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(5)
                    ? Colors.lightGreenAccent
                    : greyColor,
                radius: 18,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                3,
                2,
                color: selectedSpots.contains(6) ? Colors.red : greyColor,
                radius: 36,
              ),
              fl.ScatterSpot(
                2,
                8,
                color:
                selectedSpots.contains(7) ? Colors.tealAccent : greyColor,
                radius: 22,
              ),
            ],
            minX: 0,
            maxX: 10,
            minY: 0,
            maxY: 10,
            borderData: fl.FlBorderData(
              show: false,
            ),
            gridData: fl.FlGridData(
              show: true,
              drawHorizontalLine: true,
              checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => true,
              getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) =>
                  fl.FlLine(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
              drawVerticalLine: true,
              checkToShowVerticalLine: (value) => true,
              getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) =>
                  fl.FlLine(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
            ),
            titlesData: fl.FlTitlesData(
              show: false,
            ),
            showingTooltipIndicators: selectedSpots,
            scatterTouchData: fl.ScatterTouchData(
// ====================== Set this false =================================
              enabled: false,
              handleBuiltInTouches: true,
              touchTooltipData: fl.ScatterTouchTooltipData(
                tooltipBgColor: Colors.black,
                getTooltipItems: (fl.ScatterSpot touchedBarSpot) {
                  return fl.ScatterTooltipItem(
                    'X: ',
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      height: 1.2,
                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                    bottomMargin: 10,
                    children: [
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '${touchedBarSpot.x.toInt()} \n',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'Y: ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          height: 1.2,
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: touchedBarSpot.y.toInt().toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
              touchCallback: (fl.FlTouchEvent event,
                  fl.ScatterTouchResponse? touchResponse) {
                if (touchResponse == null ||
                    touchResponse.touchedSpot == null) {
                  return;
                }
                // Show tooltip if tap down detected
               if (event is fl.FlTapDownEvent) {
                 final sectionIndex = touchResponse.touchedSpot!.spotIndex;
                 setState(() {
                   selectedSpots.add(sectionIndex);
                 });
            // Hide/clear tooltip if long press was ended or tap up detected
              }else if(event is fl.FlLongPressEnd || event is fl.FlTapUpEvent){
                setState(() {
                  selectedSpots.clear();
                });
               }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to make it so that the popup appears when I hold it and not click it

Comment: Sorry, I've edited and tested my answer and it worked. The pop up appears if I hold it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me, some of these libraries really lack some of the customizations